# Modularizing android app based on features

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi I am very new to android development. I want to divide the parts of my app based on sections. For Eg. User Authentication, User profile, flight booking should be in different modules like in the image below-

[image]

I read alot of articles and documentation but cannot figure out how to access different activities in different module. Taking the example of image above how do I start an intent to open MainActivity in "myapplication" from MainActivity in "app". Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need include `myapplication` module to `app` module.
Open `build.gradle` file of `app` module and add this line in dependencies block:

```
    implementation project(":myapplication")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are included the `myapplication` app module in the gradle of `app`, you can import and use myapplication public class in app.
Remember that, the packagename of `MainActivity` from two app module should be differences.